# Problemas com o OBJ + MTL loader do Three.js

Tags: three.js

Estamos programando um aplicativo educacional para projeções ortogonais de poliedros que são lidos via o loader OBJ+MTL da biblioteca Three.js. O problema é que dependendo do arquivo OBJ+MTL, o loader algumas vezes não funciona e não sabemos o porquê, pois os dados parecem ok.

O método que estamos usando:

1. Carregar o poliedro usando o loader OBJ + MTL.
2. A função THREE.LineSegments() é usada para obter as arestas do poliedro.
3. A função THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry() é usada para copiar a geometria das arestas.

O problema está na Etapa 3: dependendo do arquivo de dados OBJ+MTL, a função THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry() retorna null.

Aqui está um exemplo onde tudo funciona: http://www.im-uff.mat.br/tmp/how/simple-01.html (toda a informação geométrica é passada, eixos e projeções são determinados corretamente).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está um exemplo onde há um problema com a função THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(): http://www.im-uff.mat.br/tmp/how/simple-02.html (como não foi possível copiar a geometria das arestas, as projeções nos planos coordenados falharam).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui estão os dados do poliedro que dá problemas:

OBJ:

```
####
#
# OBJ File Generated by Meshlab
#
####
# Object johnson-j01-square-pyramid.obj
#
# Vertices: 5
# Faces: 6
#
####
mtllib ./johnson-j01-square-pyramid.obj.mtl

vn -0.000270 -0.281574 -0.959539
v -0.444457 1.160279 -7.902924 
vn -0.996609 -0.000878 0.082282
v -7.610548 -2.453604 -0.243687
vn -0.105861 0.933870 0.341586
v -0.664351 5.860701 2.143697
vn 0.968495 0.248892 0.008435
v 7.942724 -0.476746 -0.828161
vn 0.125332 -0.821682 0.555996
v 0.776633 -4.090629 6.831076
# 5 vertices, 0 vertices normals

usemtl material_0
f 5//5 2//2 1//1
f 5//5 1//1 4//4

usemtl material_1
f 2//2 5//5 3//3
f 1//1 2//2 3//3
f 4//4 1//1 3//3
f 5//5 4//4 3//3
# 6 faces, 0 coords texture

# End of File
```

MTL:

```
#
# Wavefront material file
# Converted by Meshlab Group
#

newmtl material_0
Ka 0.200000 0.200000 0.200000
Kd 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ks 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Tr 1.000000
illum 2
Ns 0.000000

newmtl material_1
Ka 0.200000 0.200000 0.200000
Kd 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
Ks 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Tr 1.000000
illum 2
Ns 0.000000
```

JavaScript + HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Orthogonal Projections 2</title>

    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->

    <script src="threejs.r91/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <!-- ThreeJS Code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var transparency_value = 0;

        function MakeQuadrilateral(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
        {
           var geo = new THREE.Geometry();

            // generate vertices
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x1,y1,z1));
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x2,y2,z2));
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x3,y3,z3));
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x4,y4,z4));


            geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
            geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,2,3));


            // Return the geometry object
            return geo;
        }


       // Adds text to the screen
        function makeSpriteText(text)
        {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var size = 256; // CHANGED
            canvas.width = size;
            canvas.height = size;
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; // CHANGED
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.font = '48px Times';
            context.fillText(text, size / 2, size / 2);

            var amap = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
            amap.needsUpdate = true;

            var mat = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
                map: amap,
                transparent: false,
                useScreenCoordinates: false,
                color: 0x0000ff // CHANGED
            });

            var sp = new THREE.Sprite(mat);
            return(sp);
        }


        // Check capabilities, and start if sufficient
        var hasWebGl = (function() {try {return !! window.WebGLRenderingContext &&
                !! document.createElement('canvas').getContext('experimental-webgl');}
        catch(e){return false;}})();
        var hasCanvas = !! window.CanvasRenderingContext2D; // Converts value to boolean
        var hasVibration = navigator.vibrate;


        window.onresize = function(event)
        {
            if (loaded == true)
            {
                loaded = false;

                context0.controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(context0.camera, context0.renderer.domElement);
                context0.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
                context0.controls.noZoom = false;
                context0.controls.noPan = true;
                context0.controls.rotateSpeed = 1.2;
                context0.controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.2;
                context0.controls.staticMoving = false;
            }
        }

        if (hasCanvas)
        {
            document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
        } // End of if()

        function init()
        {
            // Setup idiom
            document.getElementById("msgwebglcontext0").innerHTML = "<br>";

            /* spawns the objects, scenes, cameras, renderers etc. */
            context0 = {color: 0xccff33, name: "0", width: 440, height: 440, factor: 30, arrowLength: 25};

            // set the scene
            if (hasWebGl)
            {
                context0.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true });
            }
            else
            {
                context0.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true });
            }
            context0.renderer.setSize(context0.width, context0.height);

            // Add the renderer to the document.
            // This should be called before THREE.TrackballControls().
            document.getElementById("webglcontext0").appendChild(context0.renderer.domElement);

            context0.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            context0.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, context0.height/context0.width, 2, 10000);   // 20: small values cause z-buffer fighting
            context0.camera.position.z = 70;
            context0.camera.position.x = 70;
            context0.camera.position.y = 70;
            context0.scene.add(context0.camera);
            context0.controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(context0.camera, context0.renderer.domElement);
            context0.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
            context0.controls.noZoom = false;
            context0.controls.noPan = true;

            // Model
            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                }
            };
            var onError = function ( xhr ) { };
            THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/' );
            mtlLoader.load( 'johnson-j01-square-pyramid.obj.mtl', function( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( 'obj/' );
                objLoader.load( 'johnson-j01-square-pyramid.obj', function ( object )
                            {

                                        object.traverse(function (child)
                                        {
                                            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
                                            {
                                                // Polyhedra
                                                child.name = "pdp-faces";
                                                context0.scene.add(child);
                                                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );
                                                console.log('From loaded OBJ: ' + geometry.vertices.length);

                                                if ( Array.isArray( child.material ) )
                                                {
                                                    var n = child.material.length;
                                                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                                                    {
                                                       child.material[i].transparent = true;
                                                       child.material[i].opacity = (1 - transparency_value/100.0);
                                                    };
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                       child.material.transparent = true;
                                                       child.material.opacity = (1 - transparency_value/100.0);
                                                }

                                                // Edges
                                                var edges = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(child.geometry), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                edges.name = "pdp-edges";
                                                context0.scene.add(edges);

                                                // Vertices
                                                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                console.log('Geometry vertices length: ' + geometry.vertices.length);
                                                var vertices = [];
                                                var isNew;
                                                var tolerance = 0.0000001;
                                                if (geometry.vertices.length > 0)
                                                {
                                                    vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[0].x, geometry.vertices[0].y, geometry.vertices[0].z));
                                                }
                                                for (i = 1; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    l = vertices.length;
                                                    isNew = true;
                                                    for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
                                                    {
                                                        var d = geometry.vertices[i].distanceTo(vertices[j]);
                                                        if (d < tolerance)
                                                        {
                                                            isNew = false;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    if (isNew == true)
                                                    {
                                                        vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[i].x, geometry.vertices[i].y, geometry.vertices[i].z));
                                                    }
                                                }

/*
                                                alert('Unique vertices: ' + vertices.length);

                                                for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    alert(vertices[i].x);
                                                }
*/
                                                // https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Polyhedra.html
                                                // https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Polyhedra.html

                                                // Fit screen
                                                child.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
                                                var fov = context0.camera.fov * ( Math.PI / 180 );
                                                var objectSize = child.geometry.boundingSphere.radius;
                                                var distance = 0.7*Math.abs( objectSize / Math.sin( fov / 2 ) );
                                                context0.camera.position.z = 2.5*distance;
                                                context0.camera.position.x = 2.5*distance;
                                                context0.camera.position.y = 2.5*distance;

                                                // PLANE PROJECTIONS
                                                var geometry_xy =  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                var geometry_xz =  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                var geometry_yz =  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                geometry_xy.dynamic = true;
                                                geometry_xz.dynamic = true;
                                                geometry_yz.dynamic = true;
                                                for (i = 0; i < geometry_xy.vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var xOld = geometry_xy.vertices[i].x;
                                                    var yOld = geometry_xy.vertices[i].y;
                                                    var zOld = geometry_xy.vertices[i].z;
                                                    geometry_xy.vertices[i].set(xOld, yOld, -distance/3);
                                                    geometry_xz.vertices[i].set(xOld, -distance/3, zOld);
                                                    geometry_yz.vertices[i].set(-distance/3, yOld, zOld);
                                                    // console.log(geometry_xy.vertices[i].x + ' ' + geometry_xy.vertices[i].y + ' ' + geometry_xy.vertices[i].z);
                                                }
                                                geometry_xy.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
                                                geometry_xz.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
                                                geometry_yz.verticesNeedUpdate = true;


                                                var edges_xy = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry_xy, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                var edges_xz = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry_xz, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                var edges_yz = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry_yz, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                edges_xy.name = "pdp-edges-xy";
                                                edges_xz.name = "pdp-edges-xz";
                                                edges_yz.name = "pdp-edges-yz";
                                                context0.scene.add(edges_xy);
                                                context0.scene.add(edges_xz);
                                                context0.scene.add(edges_yz);


                                                // VERTICES
                                                var vertexGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(child.geometry.boundingSphere.radius/35.0, 12, 6 );
                                                var vertexMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000 } );
                                                var vertexSingleMesh = new THREE.Mesh( vertexGeometry );
                                                var vertexAmalgam = new THREE.Geometry();
                                                for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var vMesh = vertexSingleMesh.clone();
                                                    vMesh.position.set(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z);
                                                    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( vertexAmalgam, vMesh );
                                                }
                                                var vertexMesh = new THREE.Mesh( vertexAmalgam, vertexMaterial );
                                                vertexMesh.name = "pdp-vertices";
                                                context0.scene.add(vertexMesh);
                                                context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-vertices").visible = false;


                                                // PLANES
                                                var d = distance/3;
                                                var xyGeometry = MakeQuadrilateral( d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    d,  d, -d,
                                                                                   -d,  d, -d,
                                                                                   -d, -d, -d);
                                                var xyPlane = new THREE.Mesh(xyGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x090909, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true }));
                                                xyPlane.name = "xyPlane";
                                                context0.scene.add(xyPlane);

                                                var d = distance/3;
                                                var xzGeometry = MakeQuadrilateral(  d, -d,  d,
                                                                                     d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    -d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    -d, -d,  d);
                                                var xzPlane = new THREE.Mesh(xzGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x090909, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true }));
                                                xzPlane.name = "xzPlane";
                                                context0.scene.add(xzPlane);

                                                var d = distance/3;
                                                var yzGeometry = MakeQuadrilateral( -d, -d,  d,
                                                                                    -d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    -d,  d, -d,
                                                                                    -d,  d,  d);
                                                var yzPlane = new THREE.Mesh(yzGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x090909, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true }));
                                                yzPlane.name = "yzPlane";
                                                context0.scene.add(yzPlane);


                                                // AXES
                                                var xVector = new THREE.ArrowHelper(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
                                                                new THREE.Vector3(-d, -d, -d ),
                                                                2*d + 0.5*d, 0x0000ff, 0.2*d, 0.1*d);
                                                xVector.name = "xVector";
                                                xVector.line.visible = true;
                                                xVector.cone.visible = true;
                                                context0.scene.add( xVector );
                                                var xLabel = makeSpriteText("y");
                                                xLabel.name = "xLabel";
                                                xLabel.position.set(d + 0.7*d, -d, -d);
                                                xLabel.scale.set( d, d, d );
                                                context0.scene.add(xLabel);

                                                var yVector = new THREE.ArrowHelper(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
                                                                new THREE.Vector3(-d, -d, -d),
                                                                2*d + 0.5*d, 0x0000ff, 0.2*d, 0.1*d);
                                                yVector.name = "yVector";
                                                yVector.line.visible = true;
                                                yVector.cone.visible = true;
                                                context0.scene.add(yVector );
                                                var yLabel = makeSpriteText("z");
                                                yLabel.name = "yLabel";
                                                yLabel.position.set(-d, d + 0.6*d, -d);
                                                yLabel.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
                                                context0.scene.add(yLabel);

                                                var zVector = new THREE.ArrowHelper(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
                                                                new THREE.Vector3(-d, -d, -d),
                                                                2*d + 0.5*d, 0x0000ff, 0.2*d, 0.1*d);
                                                zVector.name = "zVector";
                                                zVector.line.visible = true;
                                                zVector.cone.visible = true;
                                                context0.scene.add(zVector );
                                                var zLabel = makeSpriteText("x");
                                                zLabel.name = "zLabel";
                                                zLabel.position.set(-d, -d, d + 0.7*d);
                                                zLabel.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
                                                context0.scene.add(zLabel);

                                            }

                                        });

                }, onProgress, onError );
            });



            // var ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
            // context0.scene.add(ambLight);
            context0.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            context0.light.position = context0.camera.position;
            context0.scene.add(context0.light);



            // Run
            context0.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            render();
            animate();

            loaded = true;
        } // End of init()

        function animate()
        {
            /* One animation tick */
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            context0.controls.update();
            render();
        } // End of animate()

        function render()
        {
            /* renders our little scene */
            context0.renderer.render(context0.scene, context0.camera);
        } // End of render()


</script>

</head>
<body> <!--    <body onload='disableScroll();'>         -->
<center>
<span id="webglcontext0" style="width:410px; height:50px; display: table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"></span>
<div id="msgwebglcontext0" style="text-align:center; display: table; margin-left: -3px;">
<span style="width:743px; height:30px; display: table-cell; text-align:justify; padding:10px; vertical-align: middle; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
Por favor, espere o navegador carregar a pÃ¡gina. Caso
    isto jÃ¡ tenha acontecido e o applet abaixo nÃ£o executou, isto significa que seu navegador parece nÃ£o suportar WebGL ou esta opÃ§Ã£o nÃ£o estÃ¡ habilitada.
Em caso de dÃºvidas, entre em contato conosco pelo e-mail:
<a href="&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#99;&#111;&#110;&#116;&#101;&#117;&#100;&#111;&#115;&#100;&#105;&#103;&#105;&#116;&#97;&#105;&#115;&#64;&#105;&#109;&#46;&#117;&#102;&#102;&#46;&#98;&#114;">&#99;&#111;&#110;&#116;&#101;&#117;&#100;&#111;&#115;&#100;&#105;&#103;&#105;&#116;&#97;&#105;&#115;&#64;&#105;&#109;&#46;&#117;&#102;&#102;&#46;&#98;&#114;</a>.
</span>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

O que será que está acontecendo?

Comment: Arquivos tridimensionais, possuem diversas versões, você precisa trata-los antes em algum ferramenta como Blender, e exportar todo no mesma versão.

Comment: @Sveen, eu fiz isso com o Meshlab e, ainda assim, o problema continua. Além do mais, os arquivos de dados 3D parecem seguir as especificações. Será que é um bug o Three.js?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/woprbi70pc93uoz/johnson-j01-square-pyramid.rar?dl=0 tenta usar esse

Comment: @Sveen, infelizmente o problema continua: http://www.im-uff.mat.br/tmp/how/simple-03.html. Será que é um bug da biblioteca? Quem contactar neste caso?

Comment: Se tiver em alpha, provavelmente pode ser, mas tente encontrar na documentação como recupera os erros, se não tiver como, solicite